# twilight cmap for python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, colormap

I would like to use the twilight or twilight_shifted colormap in my 2.7 python build, but it seems to be python 3 only? Is there some way to manually add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`twilight` was added in matplotlib v3.0 which is python 3 only. But we can find where it was added in the source code are re-engineer it.

In the code below, you just need to grab the data used for `twilight` from the matplotlib source on github, by following this [link](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/f2116d82dfd6b82fe178230766d95ea9ac2b0c8c/lib/matplotlib/_cm_listed.py#L1288).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors

_twilight_data = [ # data too long for stack overflow. get it from here:
                   # https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/f2116d82dfd6b82fe178230766d95ea9ac2b0c8c/lib/matplotlib/_cm_listed.py#L1288
                 ]

_twilight_shifted_data = (_twilight_data[len(_twilight_data)//2:] +
                          _twilight_data[:len(_twilight_data)//2])
_twilight_shifted_data.reverse()

cmaps = {}
for (name, data) in (('twilight', _twilight_data),
                     ('twilight_shifted', _twilight_shifted_data)):

    cmaps[name] = colors.ListedColormap(data, name=name)
    # generate reversed colormap
    name = name + '_r'
    cmaps[name] = colors.ListedColormap(list(reversed(data)), name=name)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
p = ax.pcolormesh(np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5), cmap=cmaps['twilight'])
fig.colorbar(p, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

That crates a dict with `twilight`, `twilight_r`, `twilight_shifted` and `twilight_shifted_r` colormaps.

The script also produces this test image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new custom colormap as shown in this [tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html).

The data for the "twilight" and "twilight_shifted" colormaps is [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/_cm_listed.py).

Answer (score 0):

You can take the [`_cm_listed.py`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/_cm_listed.py) file from the current version and copy it to your matplotlib 2.2.3 folder. Since the file is version agnostic, this should directly give you the additional colormaps.